# No icon showing for shortcuts to Windows Apps

Tags: taskbar, icons, file-shortcut, uwp

I'm running the latest version of Windows 10, but I have had this problem for a long time now. I have shortcuts to applications in a number of places. Some key examples include on my desktop, on the taskbar, and in my Start menu. (Note that I don't use the standard Windows 10 Start menu - I have replaced it with the free Open Shell Menu program. However, this issue is not directly related to the Start menu, as it shows up in the Taskbar and desktop as well.)

The issue is that shortcuts to "standard" (Win32 EXE files) applications look just fine. The icon shows up just as one would expect, a replication of the same icon used by the EXE file. However, shortcuts to "Windows Apps" (I believe these are also known as "UWP Apps") are simply blank. Well, on the desktop, you see the little arrow in the corner indicating this is a shortcut rather than the actual app, but where the icon should be, there is nothing at all. This includes ANY "Windows App", from things I have installed from the Microsoft store to things that come preinstalled with Windows. For example, a shortcut to the "Calculator App" is completely blank, but a shortcut to the older "calc.exe" looks completely normal.

The only exception to this is the apps that show up in the "Apps" list in the sidebar of the Start menu. All of these show up normally, and correctly display their icons. However, if I try to make a shortcut to any of those apps anywhere else, the icon is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and this is how I fixed it:

- Right click the shortcut, select properties, and click the security tab.
- Select your user account and click the edit button.
- Check the box next to "full control" and press ok.
- Press ok again, to exit the properties screen.
- The icon should be restored.

You might have to reassign the icon if it doesn't come back on it's own - that can also be done through the properties screen under the shortcut tab.

If it won't let you edit the permissions, try deleting the shortcut and creating a new one, then follow the steps above again.

I hope this helps someone... took me half an hour to figure it out.

Comment: This doesn't work - When you right click on the shortcut, there is no "Properties" option in the list. I believe the "Properties" option will only show up for standard Win32 applications - it does not show up for Windows Apps ("UWP apps"), at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: Try viewing the icons in c:\Users\*your user*\AppData\Roaming\Windows\Start Menu, or wherever the icon is stored... or maybe you can drag the icon to desktop, edit the permissions, and drag it back. I am using Open Shell; that must be why I can right click for properties.

Comment: I'm also using Open Shell. The folder you mention is for icons in the Start Menu, not for the Taskbar. Taskbar icons usually show up in C:\Users\*your user*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar, but it looks like UWP icons do not.

Note that I DO get the "Properties" option for normal Windows programs (Win32 executables), just not for UWP apps.